# Проблемы с импортом react и react-dom

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp

Пытаюсь собрать сборку gulp+webpack+react. Возникли проблемы с последним. Почему-то при импорте в common.jsx react и react-dom ничего не происходит. Будто зависает так, что даже в консоль ничего не выводит. При этом, если в файле убрать всё, но оставить лишь вывод в консоль, то работать будет корректно. В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо за ответы

***common.jsx***

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

console.log(1);
const Help = (props) =>  {
            <div>
               Проверка
            </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Help />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

***package.json***

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.4",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "webpack": "^5.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.15.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

***webpack.config.js***

```
var glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: glob.sync('./src/js/**/*.jsx').reduce((acc, path) => {
    const folder = path.replace('./src/js/', '').split('/').shift()
    var name

    if (folder == 'pages') {
      name = path.split('/').pop().replace('.jsx', '')
      acc[name] = path
    }
    if (folder == 'common.jsx') {
      name = folder.replace('.jsx', '')
      acc[name] = path
    }
    
    return acc

  }, {}),
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

***.babelrc***

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
    
}
```

Comment: Настройки splitChunks намекают, что вы могли забыть подключить vendors-скрипт к html-страничке

Answer (score 0):

Потому что компонент Help ничего не возвращает, почитайте о стрелочных функциях

```
const Help = (props) => (
    <div>
        Проверка
    </div>
)
```

или

```
const Help = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Проверка
        </div>
    )
}
```